# Cannot cache dependencies on Github Actions using Pipenv

Tags: python, pip, pipenv, github-actions, building-github-actions

I am trying to cache dependencies for a Github Action workflow. I use Pipenv.

this is my config:

```
    - uses: actions/cache@v1
      with:
        path: ~/.cache/pip
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-pip-${{ hashFiles('**/Pipfile') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-pip-
```

I got this config from [Github's own examples](https://github.com/actions/cache/blob/master/examples.md#python---pip) for using pip. I have only changed `requirements.txt` to `Pipfile` since we don't use a `requirements.txt`. But even with the `requirements.txt` I get the same issue anyway.

the **Cache Dependencies** step always give this issue:

[image]

and then after running the tests:

[image]

There's no error on the workflow and it finishes as normal, however, it never seems to be able to find or update the dependency cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pipenv needed to be installed before the cache step...

```
 - name: Install pipenv, libpq, and pandoc
      run: |
        sudo apt-get install libpq-dev -y
        pip install pipenv
```

Comment: As an aside, you might want to hash `Pipfile.lock` as it contains specific version of dependencies.